# nginx check if filename with different extension exists

Tags: nginx, rewrite, request-filtering

If a file with ".html" extension doesn't exist I need to know if the same file exists with ".th.html" extension and make a redirect.

Right now on 404 I'm doing a rewrite and if $request_filename exists I do the redirect.

```
    try_files $uri $uri/ @thengine;

    error_page 404 = @thengine;

    location @thengine {
            rewrite ^/(.*)\.(htm|html)$ /$1.th.html;

            if (-f $request_filename) {
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                    proxy_intercept_errors on;
                    proxy_redirect off;

                    proxy_pass http://thengine_backend;
            }
    }
```

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do that without rewrite.

Maybe something like

```
if ($request_filename ~ (some rule to replace extension)){...}
```

Thank you.

Edit: All requests from browser will come with .html, but in case the file with .html doesn't exist, I have to check if the same file exists with .th.html and do redirect only on this case.

Edit2: Let's say someone access `domain-nginx.com/path/to/index.html`

- nginx must check if file exist, and if it does, show the page
- if file doesn't exist, look for index.th.html
- if index.th.html doesn't exist give directly 404
- if index.th.html DOES exist set some headers and `serve domain-app.com/path/to/index.th.html` (here is an application that will process these kind of templates)

All this time the user must see only `domain-nginx.com/path/to/index.html` and not see any redirect or the url to change.

Notice that .th.html is handled by another application

Comment: Can you rename the files?

Comment: I have no control over the files on the server. But how this will help?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `error_page` directive here, since you already have `@thengine` as the last part in your `try_files` directive. To answer the actual question, I need clarification what you actually want to happen..

For your actual use case, I think this is the most simple solution. You could modify the `@thengine` like this:

```
 location @thengine {
     rewrite ^/(.*)\.(htm|html)$ /$1.th.html;

     if (-f $request_filename) {
             proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
             proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
             proxy_intercept_errors on;
             proxy_redirect off;

             proxy_pass http://thengine_backend;
             break;
     }
     return 404;
}
```

However, I am not 100% sure that this configuration is safe, because of this article: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/.

The current implementation of the `if` directive in nginx easily causes unwanted side-effects, and the implementation needs to be properly checked. After reading the article above, and the article explaining `if` behavior, I still am not sure whether this solution is safe.

A safer solution could be implemented with a Lua script.

Comment: I tried with @thengine only as last directive of try_files, but doesn't seems to work; that part is never executed, that's why I put it on error_page 404. (I'm using nginx 1.10). I updated my question. I hope you can understand what I try to do now :)

Comment: I moved `try_files $uri $uri/ @thengine;` inside `location / {}` and indeed is working without the need of error_page

Answer (score -1):

This one should work. With a little help from `rewrite` engine. It is not full as you still need to check for non-existent file.

```
location /your_location {
try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.html$ /$1.th.html last;
    }
}
```

Wrong answer:

What if you try something like this:

```
try_files $uri.html $uri.th.html =404;
```

Comment: unfortunately is not having the desired behavior. Is redirecting all my traffic to @thengine even if .th.html extension doesn't exist. I updated my question with extra explanation.

Comment: `$uri` contains the complete filename. So, for example, if the request URI is `/test.html`, this solution would try `/test.html.html`, `/test.html.th.html` and then return `404`.

Comment: My answer was compltely wrong  for obvious reason, good news I have the correct one